# Getting metadata from an audio stream in Expo Go

Tags: audio, expo, metadata, expo-go

Who can tell me how to get metadata from the audio stream (icecast) in Expo Go? In documentation I see how to write my metadata, but how to get existing data I can't understand. I start the player with this code:

```
import { Audio } from 'expo-av'

await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
 playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
})
const sound = new Audio.Sound()
await sound.loadAsync({ uri: URL }
await sound.playAsync()
```

The documentation has an AVMetadata type, but it is not at all clear how to use it.

[Screenshot of documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHDum.png)